# Bevel not working on object

Tags: mesh, modifiers, edit-mode, bevel, solidify-modifier

I am following a very speedy tutorial that isnt explaining steps. im trying to apply bevel modifier to these sunglass models. mirror above and subsurf + solidify below. if I switch to angle mode mesh reacts in a bad way, tutorial seems to use weight limit method but for me it does nothing.

scale is not applied, when i do mesh goes into a big ball.

[image]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4WxNdhwMsP4&ab_channel=DerekElliott

link to video here 7:46

Not sure if I need to flatten mesh, apply solidify (doesnt work well), or something else?

[image]

Comment: Please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: First of all, the geometry seems a bit messed up and overlapping near the nose-piece (not the issue you asked about, but might be a problem later). Then in the tutorial the _Solidify_ modifier is applied, yours not since your frame is just made of flat faces. Then the _Bevel_ modifier is set to _Limit Method_ > _Weight_, but as you can see in your screenshot the _Mean Bevel Weight_ with all edges selected is 0, so none of these  edges would be beveled, even if you had applied the _Solidify_ modifier. By the way, you do not have to apply it yet, but then is has to be above the _Bevel_ modifier.